USB Drive Not Showing Up In File Dialog
I recently purchased a USB drive to load Windows 11 onto. It's showing up in Disks and lsblk (57.7G 0 disk). However, it doesn't show up in the Files GUI alongside my other drives so I can't drag files onto it.
I thought about using terminal to copy my files onto it but when I entered it into another computer it didn't read it either.
How can I get this USB to show up in my GUI? I formatted the drive to msdos using gparted but it still isn't showing up anywhere in my GUI and I doubt it would be read by my new computer.
Thanks.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup
